# Wireless connection suddenly drops Intel 3945ABG

Tags: networking, drivers, lubuntu, network-manager, 17.10

I have an old laptop Toshiba SATELLITE L350-150 with an Intel® PRO/Wireless 3945ABG network card.

I used mkusb to create a persistent USB stick with Lubuntu 17.10.

Booting the OS works fine and the wireless connection works well, until suddenly it drops. Network manager indicates 'Device not ready'.

The [latest firmware](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlegacy?s[]=iwl3945#firmware) 15.32.2.9 is used (see lshw output).

Any ideas how to fix this?

**Troubleshooting**

Did not solve the problem

```
sudo service network-manager restart

sudo modprobe -r iwl3945 && sudo modprobe iwl3945
```

Here is some output:

**Network-manager**

```
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo service network-manager status 

● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-03-02 18:15:05 CET; 32min ago
     Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
 Main PID: 1503 (NetworkManager)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
           └─1503 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

mrt 02 18:47:13 lubuntu NetworkManager[1503]: <info>  [1520012833.5817] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: starting -> down
mrt 02 18:47:23 lubuntu NetworkManager[1503]: <warn>  [1520012843.6283] device (wlp3s0): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#1).
mrt 02 18:47:24 lubuntu NetworkManager[1503]: <error> [1520012844.1776] sup-iface[0x55e96410c5c0,wlp3s0]: error adding interface: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
mrt 02 18:47:24 lubuntu NetworkManager[1503]: <info>  [1520012844.1777] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: starting -> down
mrt 02 18:47:34 lubuntu NetworkManager[1503]: <warn>  [1520012854.6367] device (wlp3s0): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#2).
mrt 02 18:47:35 lubuntu NetworkManager[1503]: <error> [1520012855.1842] sup-iface[0x55e96410c2a0,wlp3s0]: error adding interface: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
mrt 02 18:47:35 lubuntu NetworkManager[1503]: <info>  [1520012855.1843] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: starting -> down
mrt 02 18:47:45 lubuntu NetworkManager[1503]: <warn>  [1520012865.6367] device (wlp3s0): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#3).
mrt 02 18:47:46 lubuntu NetworkManager[1503]: <error> [1520012866.1907] sup-iface[0x55e96406b530,wlp3s0]: error adding interface: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
mrt 02 18:47:46 lubuntu NetworkManager[1503]: <info>  [1520012866.1907] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: starting -> down
```

**lspci**

```
lubuntu@lubuntu: lspci 
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection (rev 02)
```

**lshw**

```
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:1f:3c:8a:71:54
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwl3945 driverversion=4.13.0-21-generic firmware=15.32.2.9 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:27 memory:d4300000-d4300fff
```

**rfkill**

```
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**dmesg**

```
[ 1976.616299] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[ 1978.103671] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[ 1978.117286] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[ 1978.117386] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[ 1978.120365] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[ 1978.168538] iwl3945 0000:03:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xa5a5a5a2, s/b 0xf802020
[ 1978.168548] iwl3945 0000:03:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
[ 1978.215241] iwl3945 0000:03:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xa5a5a5a2, s/b 0xf802020
[ 1978.215247] iwl3945 0000:03:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
[ 1978.261955] iwl3945 0000:03:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xa5a5a5a2, s/b 0xf802020
[ 1978.261960] iwl3945 0000:03:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
[ 1978.308659] iwl3945 0000:03:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xa5a5a5a2, s/b 0xf802020
[ 1978.308665] iwl3945 0000:03:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
[ 1978.355358] iwl3945 0000:03:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xa5a5a5a2, s/b 0xf802020
[ 1978.355362] iwl3945 0000:03:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
[ 1978.392715] iwl3945 0000:03:00.0: Unable to initialize device after 5 attempts.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling the power saving function fixed the problem.

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
```